# Java Apps - AWT rendering leads to broken text with antialiasing on

Tags: java, netbeans, awt, rendering, antialiasing

My system :

*win 7 x64 sp1*

Whatever jre x64 i try to set :

*1.6.17 - 1.60.31 - 1.7.27 - 1.7.45*

I got an issue whit java apps like MPLABX, netbeans , java notepad demo and so on..  eclipse runs well so it leads me suspect on AWT.

When Antialising is  active ,cleartype enabled , java text renderer brokes text when mouse pass over , example :

```
"FILE"  string from a menu item after mouse over becomes "FI  "
```

With applications AA settings not overridden , those apps natively don't use AA   :

```
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=false
```

text repaint works fine.

I know in jre 7 AA has changed but i got another system very similar to this one where text rendering is good with any kind of jre.

Maybe some conflicts with some native rendering libs corrupted on windows ? How to investigate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved but not understood completly by disabling 3D acceleration on VM settings where system was running.

Comment: Which way did you use to disable it?

Comment: Virtual machine settings->display->3d acceleration